# Given number of days and date then find the start or end date in python

Tags: python, python-datetime

I understand there's an package "date" from "datetime"
for solving "Calculate numbers of days between two given date", but this is not what I am looking for

Let me give an example to further describe my question.

let says:10 days and the baseline is 2021/09/09
I want to know the date before 10 days 8/30 is clearly the answer I am looking for

It might be an easy question. still needs for help. Thanks

Comment: The module `datetime` is indeed what you're looking for. Have you tried using that module to solve your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might just work:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

day1 = date(2021, 9, 9)
difference = timedelta(days=10)
day2 = day1 - difference #Your answer
print(day2)
```

Comment: oh my god, I am totally not familiar with the timedelta function. thanks for answering

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
from datetime import datetime  
from datetime import timedelta  

print(datetime.now() - timedelta(days=10))
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you are looking for this. You can also pass day as datetime object

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def get_start_end_day(day, delta):
    if isinstance(day, str):
        day = datetime.strptime(day, '%Y/%m/%d')
    return day - timedelta(days=delta), day + timedelta(days=delta)

days = get_start_end_day('2021/09/09', 10)

print(days)
```

output

```
(datetime.datetime(2021, 8, 30, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 19, 0, 0))
```